# Tensorflow interleaved input pipeline becomes very slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

#### System information

- **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow)**: Yes
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**: Windows 7
- **Mobile device (e.g. iPhone 8, Pixel 2, Samsung Galaxy) if the issue happens on mobile device**:
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**: Binary
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**: 1.13
- **Python version**: 3.7
- **Bazel version (if compiling from source)**:
- **GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source)**:
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**: 9
- **GPU model and memory**: GTX 980 4GB
- **Exact command to reproduce**:

#### Describe the problem

I am building a pipeline to feed a DNNRegressor model and the issue is that the input pipeline becomes extremely slow after the first few 100's steps.

I have thousands of TFRecord files of varying size (from 10MB to 3GB in size). Each input has 1038 columns. 
I am trying to create batches of size 512 with 1 "row" from each TFRecord file (each file has correlated data so I need 1 line from each of the 512 files being interleaved to have a "shuffled" batch). To do this,
I am using the Data.interleave method which seems perfect for my case.

Problem is the input is super fast at the start but gets painfully slow after the first 100's of steps.
CPU usage goes quickly from 100% at the start to near 0% as the pipeline becomes slower. However the disk read speed remains always at  > 60 MBps. What is the issue ? Are the smaller files straggling the pipeline in someway ?

I have tried using parralel interleave but that was even slower

#### Source code / logs

```
def parse_tf(example):
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        parsed_features = tf.parse_example(example, feature)
        feats = parsed_features
        labels = parsed_features.pop('labels')
        return feats, labels


def tf_input_fn(batch_size):
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        files = os.listdir('D:/data/data')
        files = ['D:/data/data/' + file for file in files]

        dataset = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)
                   .interleave(lambda x:
                               tf.data.TFRecordDataset(x),
                               cycle_length=batch_size, block_length=1, num_parallel_calls=8)).batch(batch_size).map(
            parse_tf, num_parallel_calls=1)

        dataset = dataset.prefetch(100)
        return dataset


if __name__ == "__main__":

    batch_size_ = 512

    data = tf_input_fn(batch_size_)
    data_next = data.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    ctr = 0
    with tf.Session() as data_sess:
        data_sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        tld_start = dt.datetime.now()
        try:
            while True:
                tld_out = data_sess.run(data_next)
                ctr += 1
                if ctr % 100 == 0:
                    tld_end = dt.datetime.now()
                    print("Time for 100 steps: " + str(tld_end - tld_start))
                    tld_start = dt.datetime.now()
                    ctr = 0
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print("Done")
```

Logs:

```
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:04.547647
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:03.132636
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:02.839416
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:02.639220
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:02.492228
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:01.991023
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:12.380473
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:29.162056
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:23.747592
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:28.041797
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:28.309055
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:26.240207
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:27.894402
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:25.832465
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:27.795538
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:28.219248
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:26.962029
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:24.568246
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:29.052262
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:27.003928
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:27.839937
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:28.380154
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:27.109850
Time for 100 steps: 0:00:28.234840
```